# Failing to manually create usable single-file assembly

Tags: visual-c++, dll, manifest, assemblies

I'm developing a big set of C++ plugin dlls for an external application (using Visual Studio 2017 with the 2015 toolchain if that matters).  These plugins in turn share a lot of code, so I put that in it's own common dll file named common.inc (I can't use the .dll extension on it, otherwise the host app mistakes it for a regular plugin).  I'd prefer to put this common dll file just next to the other plugin dlls for ease of distributing.  The common.inc needs to be pulled in via load-time linking, i.e. not via manual LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress calls (there's just too many entryways into the common.inc to wrap).

This should all work out-of-the-box, were it not for the fact that the host application doesn't play fair here.  The host app seems to be using a flat LoadLibrary against the plugins it finds, specifying the full path to the plugins, and doesn't bother to set the current dir to the plugin folder, nor use LoadLibraryEx to specify an additional search path or such.  The result is that my plugin dlls can't possibly link up to the common.inc right next to them...

I'd like not to pollute the path env var with the host app's plugin folder, nor do I want to install the common.inc into the host app's install folder or (shudder) windows folder.  My solution so far is to use manifest files to direct the Windows loader to common.inc when loading up the plugin dlls, defining a private assembly with common.inc in it.

I got it working, but it's not nice (enough) as-is.  I'm currently placing common.inc in a "CommonFolder" folder next to the plugins, and place a CommonFolder.manifest in that folder reffing the common.inc inside it.  It's a multi-file assembly set-up of sorts I assume, but only using 1 file.  I'd like to morph this in a true single-file assembly to get rid of the extra folder + external manifest file, but I can't seem to get it to work.

What I have so far, which works, is:

plugin.dll's embedded manifest (@ ID 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="CommonFolder" version="1.0.0.0"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <...trustinfo section left out...>
</assembly>
```

CommonFolder's content:

- common.inc without any embedded manifest
- CommonFolder.manifest

CommonFolder.manifest in turn contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="CommonFolder" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <file name="Common.inc" />
</assembly>
```

What I'm stuck at, which doesn't work, is:

plugin.dll's embedded manifest (@ ID 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Common.inc" version="1.0.0.0"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <...trustinfo section left out...>
</assembly>
```

common.inc next to plugin.dll, with an embedded manifest (@ ID 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Common.inc" version="1.0.0.0"></assemblyIdentity>
  <file name="Common.inc"></file>
  <...trustinfo section left out...>
</assembly>
```

I'm probably goofing up big-time here, but I had to give myself a crash course on what manifest files were in the first place.  Now that I'm getting more comfortable with manifests, they actually seem quite a simple concept, but the docs I could Google up all seem to fail to convey that in a straight-forward way (often getting waaay too meta about them and thus diluting the actual topic, or only listing all available low-level flags and XML tags without properly relating them to higher-level concepts).

Comment: That's a pretty standard chicken-and-egg mistake in manifests.  The embedded manifest cannot be activated until the loader finds the DLL first.  It can't find common.inc unless the plugin manifest tells it where to look.

Comment: @HansPassant: Seems legit :) So then the only option here is indeed a multi-file assembly, since then the assembly (folder) can be found at all times?

Comment: I stopped assuming quite a while ago that Junfeng Zhang's terminology carries any actual useful meaning.  His MSDN documentation, when printed out, can easily stop a 20mm caliber depleted uranium bullet fired from a Vulcan cannon.  Stick with what you have.